# Got access to .ssh folder on server - how to SSH into it?

Tags: ssh, ssh-host-key

Doing a challenge at work. Managed to get netcat to connect to a server. In /home/SomeUser there is a .ssh folder with the usual suspects:

```
authorized_hosts 
authorized_keys 
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
known_hosts
known_hosts.back
```

My question is, now that I can see this (via netcat) how could I now SSH into the server?

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't.

The only information you can get out of this is:

- `id_rsa*`: key pair probably created at some point and never used. Even then, the private key is probably passphrase protected.
- `authorized_keys`: will list the public keys that can be used to ssh in as that user. If you have access to one of the matching private keys, then great: you're in. Otherwise it doesn't help you much.

Now, if you could modify any of this (well, you would already be in, wouldn't you?) you could add your public key to `authorized_keys`.

Comment: I echo'd my public key to authorized_keys and imported the ppk into putty but it still says the server refused the key

Comment: So you can modify files on the remote host. How is that not already having access to it?

Comment: As part of the challenge is to connect via SSH

Comment: Ok, then make sure you 1) added the key in the right format ("ssh-rsa <some big base64 blob> <some identifier>"), 2) passed the right key to putty (I don't know how putty uses keys, I just know plain ssh), 3) tried logging in with the right user. Also make sure you don't modify the permissions on the `authorized_keys` file or sshd will reject it.

Comment: @pee2pee - further to Marcs comment key based authentication may be disabled by the server. If you can access the config check it and if necessary modify then restart the server.